# wsimport: undeclared namespace prefix

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsimport

> wsimport  https://api2.autotrade.su/api.wsdl

gives me this:

> [ERROR] undeclared namespace prefix: "ns2"   line 302 of
>   https://api2.autotrade.su/api.wsdl
>
> [ERROR] undeclared namespace prefix: "ns2"   line 328 of
>   https://api2.autotrade.su/api.wsdl
>
> [ERROR] undeclared namespace prefix: "nxsd"   line 454 of
>   https://api2.autotrade.su/api.wsdl
>
> [ERROR] "Use of SOAP Encoding is not supported. SOAP extension element
>   on line 775 in https://api2.autotrade.su/api.wsdl has use="encoded" "

is this service wsdl-compatible? How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not valid. You need to correct it yourself. The line 454 is simple misspelled should be xsd instead of nxsd. You would have to think what the namespace for Map should be, judging by other declarations something like namesp1:ArrayOfSOMETHING